# Angular call function of two same child component

Tags: angular, parent-child

I'm trying to call a child component function, the problem is that I have 2 times this child component in the parrent and when I click on any button it calls the first child function everytime.

My code looks like this:

```
<div class="child-container">
  <child-component #firstChild></child-component>
  <button (click)="firstChild.refresh()"></button>
</div>
<div class="child-container">
  <child-component #secondChild></child-component>
  <button (click)="secondChild.refresh()"></button>
</div>
```

What do I do wrong ? Is there any way to solve my problem ? Thanks.

Comment: This minimum code looks right - what's happening in refresh fn? Can you create a stackbliz of minimum reproducible code?

Comment: i can't reproduce it. here is a sample working example : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-pnzqgd?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html. Try to use it as a base to illustrate your problem

Comment: my child component is a really complex tree that load the nodes when you click on expand and the refresh button refresh all the nodes that have been opened before. It's too hard to make a stackblitz. But when i click on any refresh button it refresh the nodes of the first tree :s

Comment: You can add a string as `refresh()` parameter to be sure that the function is called by the second argument like this ```secondChild.refresh('2nd')```, after that you can `console.log(param)` inside your `refresh(param: string)`